# Is Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray() to a string (number) line still unique

Tags: c#, guid

I need to generate a unique id which consists of numbers.

Is the following result string `uniqueId` as unique as the result of `guid.ToString()`?

```
Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
byte[] guidBytes = guid.ToByteArray();

// Is the result (uniqueId) as unique as guid.ToString()?
string uniqueId = string.Join(string.Empty, guidBytes);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a 1:1 mapping of byte arrays to Guids. No information is lost during the transformation so you still retain the same uniqueness as using the normal string representation of a Guid.

A Guid really is just a 16 byte number, it does not matter if you show it as `{3F2504E0-4F89-41D3-9A0C-0305E82C3301}`, `4AQlP4lP00GaDAMF6CwzAQ==` or as `224004037063137079211065154012003005232044051001`, it all still represents the same number.

**EDIT:** Oops, [as mkysoft ponted out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40555598/80274), you do have to deal with leading zeros. Padding the numbers to 3 digits solves the issue

```
var guid = new Guid("{3F2504E0-4F89-41D3-9A0C-0305E82C3301}");
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(string.Empty, guid.ToByteArray().Select(x=>x.ToString("000"))));
```

**UPDATE:** Actually I just thought of a better solution, a Guid is a 128-bit number, by using 2 64-bit numbers and padding the number's 0's out on the 2nd half you will get a shorter, but still unique number.

```
var guid = new Guid("{3F2504E0-4F89-41D3-9A0C-0305E82C3301}");
var guidBytes = guid.ToByteArray();
Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}", BitConverter.ToUInt64(guidBytes, 0), BitConverter.ToUInt64(guidBytes,8).ToString().PadLeft(20, '0'));
```

This will output a unique integer number that is between 21 and 40 digits long,  `{3F2504E0-4F89-41D3-9A0C-0305E82C3301}` becomes `474322228343976880000086462192878292122`,

Comment: As pointed out by @myyosft, there is intersection without leading zeros? In which case does this occur? How do three digits solve the problem (why not e.g. 4 digits)?

Comment: @Odrai The biggest value for a byte is 255, so 000,001,...,254,255. Hex is more compact, 00,01,...,FE,FF.

Comment: @Odrai If I give you the number `425` was the source number `4, 25` or `42, 5`? by adding leading zeros it makes it `004025`, now there is no ambiguity between which one was chosen. A byte can represent any number between 0 and 255, we use 3 digits because the largest number a byte can represent is 3 digits long.

Comment: @Odrai see my latest update. I came up with a better solution that will end up with shorter numbers. Works on the same principal we where doing with the individual `byte` objects but it works with 2 `Uint64`s instead of 16 `byte`s. Also I realized you don't need the leading 0's on the first byte/UInt64, so that is where a lot of the space savings comes from.

Answer (score 5):

You need seperator between byte values or fill with zero. Otherwise there is intersection.
Example: 3,5,6,7,123 => 003005006007123

Comment: +1, alternatively you could ensure each byte is represented by three characters. (with leading zeroes as padding)

Answer (score 3):

Or you could use BigInteger.ToString() to handle making big numbers into strings (since it's really good at that)

```
var p = Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray();
Array.Resize(ref p, p.Length + 1);

Console.WriteLine(new BigInteger(p));
```

The resize is only if you require positive numbers (otherwise there is a 50% chance you get a negative number). You could also use `System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator.GetBytes` to have a larger or smaller set of values (depending on how big you want your identifiers to be)

Comment: Good idea bout the `BigIntiger`! totally forgot about that. That is even better than my last update.